# How to remove an add-on that crashes Blender for Ubuntu on launch?

Tags: blender

I installed and enabled the Rokoko add-on for mocap retargeting and now Blender crashes every time I try to launch it. I'm using the latest releases of Blender and Ubuntu.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Blender but that didn't help and I've tried searching for the .py file to manually delete it, but I can't find it. Does anyone know where the add-on would be located after installation on Ubuntu or what the Rokoko add-on might be called?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/293145/where-are-third-party-addons-stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by [this answer on Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/293145/where-are-third-party-addons-stored):

```
$HOME/.config/blender/3.5/scripts/addons/
```

Maybe 3.5 becomes 3.6 with the latest Blender.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think the search didn't succeed because .config is a hidden folder.